# Ajax being called twice on setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I'm doing ajax calls in a specific time interval using javascript setInterval function however the ajax code is being executed twice, so I'm getting the same response twice and I have no idea why this is happening, here's the code:

```
        setInterval(function () {ajaxCall();},15000);

        function ajaxCall(){
            var uri = "url here";
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: uri,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    var txt = $("#textarea");
                    txt.val( txt.val() + response.user + " (" + response.time + ") > " 
                    + response.text + '\n');
                    }
            });
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: that code should produce one call every 15 seconds.  Something else must be going on in code you are not showing us.  perhaps you are setting up the interval more than once...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What you have will call the ajaxCall function every 15 seconds. Are you saying it's called twice every 15 seconds?

Comment: That's the only script right now in my html so nothing should be interfering with it.
As for what I'm trying to accomplish is calling a web service for a json every 15 seconds. So yeah it's being called twice every 15 seconds.

Comment: I would normally do the call after every success using jQuery.Deferred functionality.

Comment: Never tried it before and while I found a solution I will try that also, thx for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I just figured it out, I had that script inside the html body tag but if I move it inside head tags it stops calling it twice, not sure why this is but it solved the problem.
Sorry for wasting your time for something that simple xD